# Issue in Table data in angular.Printing multiple times at each row

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a table which i'm trying to feed three data that is itemTitle,itemValue and itemUnit.

```
This is my model 
export class HubxDataModel{ 
    categoryId:number;
    categoryName:string;
    HubxDataItems:HubxModel;
}
export class HubxModel{ 
    id: number;
    categoryId: number;
    itemTitle: string;
    itemUnit: string;
    isActive: boolean=true;
    itemValue: string;
    patientId: number;
    isDeleted: boolean;
}
```

and this is how i declare my model in my component class

```
hubxReportList : Array<HubxDataModel> = [];
```

And this is my table header

```
headers = ["Test Name","Result","Unit"];
```

and this is the Html that i used to create my table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let column of headers">
       {{column}}
   </th>
 </tr>
 <tr *ngFor="let item of hubxReport.hubxDataItems">
   <td *ngFor="let column of headers">
      {{item.itemTitle}}{{item.itemValue}}{{item.itemUnit}}
  </td>
 </tr>
```

I'll share my table image.Here HBA1C is the itemTitle(Test Name), 18 is the itemValue(Result) and mmol is the itemUnit(Unit).All the three data is priting in each column multiple times.How can i fix it.
[image: table]

the code i tried to solve the issue but having issue. At the below line of i'm trying to supply column data

```
{{item.itemTitle[column]}}{{item.itemValue[column]}}{{item.itemUnit[column]}}
```

but this code has issue i think i have to specify which column should be used in itemTitle,itemValue and itemUnit.
I need to know the correct way to specify the below code is what i tried to specify the columns data

```
{{item.itemTitle[column == "TestName"]}}{{item.itemValue[column == "Result" ]}}{{item.itemUnit[column == "Unit"]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restructure the html like so. We can use `*ngFor` for creating each row of the table, then for each of the `th` cells, we will create a corresponding `td` cell which will store the column value!

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let column of headers">
         {{column}}
     </th>
   </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let item of hubxReport.hubxDataItems">
        <td>{{item.itemTitle}}</td>
        <td>{{item.itemValue}}</td>
        <td>{{item.itemUnit}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```